# Tutorial client/server for iphone apps

Tags: iphone, client

I have experience developing iphone apps, but I am a complete novice when it comes to building a server. Do you guys know of any good tutorials/books that could guide me on how to build a client/server app.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Ray Wenderlich has a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app) on building a web service for an iPhone app.

Your 'question' is also not very specific and very broad.